# what is wrong in this table

Tags: tables, texmaker

could any body please tell me what is wrong in this table?

```
\begin{table}[!h]\label{Table}
  \caption{Running times in seconds on  symmetric MINLP.}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\centering}Xc}
  \toprule
      Name  & Symmetry group & Generators of the group \\
  \midrule
  P1     &   Cyclic group $ C_{5} $ & $(1,2,3,4,5)$ \\
    \midrule
 P2 &  Primitive group (15,2) & $ (1,15,7,5,12)$  $(2,9,13,14,8)$  $(3,6,10,11,4), $  $ (1,4,5)$  $(2,8,10$  $)(3,12,15)$  $(6,13,11)$  $(7,9,14)$ \\

P3 &   Primitive group (21,2) & $(1,7,12,16,19,21,6)$, $(2,8,13,17,20,5,11)$, $(3,9,14,18,4,10,15)$,
  $(4,6,5)$, $(9,11,10)$, $(13,15,14)$, $(16,18,17)$, $(19,20,21)$  \\
  \midrule

P4 & Primitive group (45,2) & $ ( 1, 2, 7)$  $( 3,11,27)$  $( 4,14,31)$  $( 5,18,32)$ $( 6,20,36)$  $( 8,24,39)$  $( 9,25,28)$  $(10,26,42)$  $(12,15,16)$  $(13,30,40)$  $(17,19,21)$ $(22,35,44)$  $(23,33,29)$  $(34,43,37)$  $(38,45,41)$,$ ( 1, 3, 5, 6, 7,22,13,23)$  $( 2, 8, 9,10)$ $( 4,15,16,17,14,21,19,12
     )$  $(11,28,29,38,44,25,20,37)$  $(18,33,34,24,40,36,41,39)$ $(26,43,35,32,42,45,27,
     30)$, $( 1, 4)$  $( 3,12)$  $( 5,19)$  $( 6,21)$  $( 7,14)$  $( 8,10)$  $(11,20)$  $(13,16)$  $(15,23)$ $
    (17,22)$  $(18,33)$  $(24,41)$  $(25,28)$  $(26,43)$  $(27,32)$  $(29,44)$  $(30,35)$  $(34,39)$  $(36,40)$  $(42,45) $  \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please exend your table code to complete small document, which we can test as it is ...

Comment: The stuff that is currently in your third column will never fit if you don't allow line breaks.

Comment: @leandriis what I should do?

Comment: For the third, column, use a column type that allows linebreaks. Such column types are `p`, `b`, `m` or as you already used: `X`. I have added an answer to show how.

Answer (score 5):

Based on some assumptions on your documentclass, the used packages and the desired output, here is my guess:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]\label{Table}
  \caption{Running times in seconds on  symmetric MINLP.}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccC}
  \toprule
      Name  & Symmetry group & Generators of the group \\
  \midrule
  P1     &   Cyclic group $ C_{5} $ & $(1,2,3,4,5)$ \\
    \midrule
 P2 &  Primitive group (15,2) & $ (1,15,7,5,12)$  $(2,9,13,14,8)$  $(3,6,10,11,4), $  $ (1,4,5)$  $(2,8,10$  $)(3,12,15)$  $(6,13,11)$  $(7,9,14)$ \\

P3 &   Primitive group (21,2) & $(1,7,12,16,19,21,6)$, $(2,8,13,17,20,5,11)$, $(3,9,14,18,4,10,15)$,
  $(4,6,5)$, $(9,11,10)$, $(13,15,14)$, $(16,18,17)$, $(19,20,21)$  \\
  \midrule

P4 & Primitive group (45,2) & $ ( 1, 2, 7)$  $( 3,11,27)$  $( 4,14,31)$  $( 5,18,32)$ $( 6,20,36)$  $( 8,24,39)$  $( 9,25,28)$  $(10,26,42)$  $(12,15,16)$  $(13,30,40)$  $(17,19,21)$ $(22,35,44)$  $(23,33,29)$  $(34,43,37)$  $(38,45,41)$,$ ( 1, 3, 5, 6, 7,22,13,23)$  $( 2, 8, 9,10)$ $( 4,15,16,17,14,21,19,12
     )$  $(11,28,29,38,44,25,20,37)$  $(18,33,34,24,40,36,41,39)$ $(26,43,35,32,42,45,27,
     30)$, $( 1, 4)$  $( 3,12)$  $( 5,19)$  $( 6,21)$  $( 7,14)$  $( 8,10)$  $(11,20)$  $(13,16)$  $(15,23)$ $
    (17,22)$  $(18,33)$  $(24,41)$  $(25,28)$  $(26,43)$  $(27,32)$  $(29,44)$  $(30,35)$  $(34,39)$  $(36,40)$  $(42,45) $  \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Mine guessing is slightly different :-) :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Running times in seconds on  symmetric MINLP.}
  \label{Table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}C
                                    >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C
                               @{} }
  \toprule
      Name  & Symmetry group & Generators of the group \\
  \midrule
  P1     &   Cyclic group $ C_{5} $ & $(1,2,3,4,5)$ \\
    \midrule
 P2 &  Primitive group (15,2) & $ (1,15,7,5,12)$  $(2,9,13,14,8)$  $(3,6,10,11,4), $  $ (1,4,5)$  $(2,8,10$  $)(3,12,15)$  $(6,13,11)$  $(7,9,14)$ \\

P3 &   Primitive group (21,2) & $(1,7,12,16,19,21,6)$, $(2,8,13,17,20,5,11)$, $(3,9,14,18,4,10,15)$,
  $(4,6,5)$, $(9,11,10)$, $(13,15,14)$, $(16,18,17)$, $(19,20,21)$  \\
  \midrule

P4 & Primitive group (45,2) & $ ( 1, 2, 7)$  $( 3,11,27)$  $( 4,14,31)$  $( 5,18,32)$ $( 6,20,36)$  $( 8,24,39)$  $( 9,25,28)$  $(10,26,42)$  $(12,15,16)$  $(13,30,40)$  $(17,19,21)$ $(22,35,44)$  $(23,33,29)$  $(34,43,37)$  $(38,45,41)$,$ ( 1, 3, 5, 6, 7,22,13,23)$  $( 2, 8, 9,10)$ $( 4,15,16,17,14,21,19,12
     )$  $(11,28,29,38,44,25,20,37)$  $(18,33,34,24,40,36,41,39)$ $(26,43,35,32,42,45,27,
     30)$, $( 1, 4)$  $( 3,12)$  $( 5,19)$  $( 6,21)$  $( 7,14)$  $( 8,10)$  $(11,20)$  $(13,16)$  $(15,23)$ $
    (17,22)$  $(18,33)$  $(24,41)$  $(25,28)$  $(26,43)$  $(27,32)$  $(29,44)$  $(30,35)$  $(34,39)$  $(36,40)$  $(42,45) $  \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: label for table had to be after caption!